# Symfony 4.3 - Overriding template issue the EasyAdminBundle's layout.html.twig case

Tags: templates, overriding, symfony4, easyadmin, symfony-4.3

I'm integrating EasyAdminBundle to my Symfony 4.3 app.
No problems except the overring template part ..
Fllowing the documentation, the template's overriding mechanism seems not work at all...

I'm forcely missing something ..

Example with the layout of EasyAdminBundle (easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v2.3.0):

Following the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html#overriding-the-default-templates-using-symfony-s-mechanism) my structure is like :

```
my-project/
├─ ...
└─ templates/
   └─ bundles/
      └─ EasyAdminBundle/
         └─ default/
            ├─ layout.html.twig
```

This layout.html.twig (path:*templates/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/default/layout.html.twig*) is a copy of the *vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Resources/views/default/layout.html.twig* + some modifications

Cache:clear in debug and refresh navigator doesn't change the layout ( the effective one is still : vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Resources/views/default/layout.html.twig )

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

After adding in easy_admin.yaml :

```
  design:
    templates:
      layout: 'bundles/EasyAdminBundle/default/layout.html.twig'
```

The layout is well used by the easyadmin views ...

But shouldn't be working without it ?